# TypeError: foo is undefined when trying to call it in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have this small method.

```
$cargos = JSON.parse('<?php echo $cargos ?>');
$html = '';

console.log($cargos[0][0]); //correct printing of the desired values

for(var x=0;x <= $cargos.length;x++)
{
   console.log(x); //this prints the numbers correctly
   $html += "<option value='"+$cargos[x][0]+"'>"+$cargos[x][1]+"</option>"; //error, $cargos[x] is undefined
}
```

I'm retrieving a (multidimentional) array from PHP using JSON, and I plan to do a small loop with it however I can't use the variable `x` when calling the array elements because I get an error.

```
TypeError: $cargos[x] is undefined
```

If I try to call the indexes manually using numbers they print correctly without errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Off-by-one error: use `<` not `<=`, since `$cargos[$cargos.length]` is not defined (being zero-indexed, it only goes up to `$cargos.length-1`)

Comment: I can't believe I missed something so trivial. Thank you. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array's index start from zero in Javascript. So when iterating through an array from start to end, you should traverse from index `0` to `length-of-array - 1`. You can simple replace `<=` with `<` in the termination condition of your loop and it should work fine.